# Laggy mouse cursor on windows guest

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, kvm, virt-manager

I have virt-manager, qemu, kvm setup. I have  installed Windows 11 and Arch Linux guests. On Arch Linux, I don't have any additional guest drives for virtualization to work.

On Arch Linux, when the cursor moves from host to guest window, host cursor is used. However, on Windows, the Windows cursor is used within the guest window and host cursor disappears. On VirtualBox, with the guest drivers installed, I can use the host cursor and there is no cursor lag (i think there was an option to enable that behavior). On Windows 11, I had installed VirtIO guest tools installed first. It did not fixed the issue so I installed spice-guest-tools after that which also didn't work. Is it possible to use host cursor within Windows guest?

Comment: I don't use virt-manager, but for QEMU using these flags solve the problem for me: -vga qxl -usb -device usb-tablet. You also need to install spice guest tools in your guest.